# Выполнение JS скрипта с cookie от браузера (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, cookie

Добрый вечер.

Такая ситуация: есть *JavaScript* код, который использует в ходе своего выполнения записи из Cookie. Как я могу выполнить, этот *JavaScript* код через программу *C#*, через браузер по умолчанию (браузер по умолчанию в операционной системе) и что бы этот код видел те cookie, которые записаны в браузере на этот сайт.

Уже долго думал, как можно осуществить и не вышло.

Надеюсь вы поняли проблему. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Вообщем нужно выполнить JS (через программу c#) скрипт используя cookie, с браузера по умолчанию. Именно те cookie которые пользователь получает смотря сайты.

Comment: вы хотите запустить браузер и получить из него результат выполнения js скрипта?

Comment: Да... Только JS скрипт пишу я, его на сайте нет.